# A physical system is described by the following Lagrangian: $ L = \frac{m}{2} (\dot{\rho}² + \rho ² \dot{\phi} ² + \dot{z} ²) + a \rho² \dot{\phi}$

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

Where $a$ is a constant and $(\rho,\phi,z)$ are cylindrical coordinates. I found the following Hamiltonian $ H =\frac{m}{2}(\dot{\rho}² + \dot{z}² + \rho²\dot{\phi}²)$. The problem asked me to find three constants of movement, then I found $\frac{d}{dt}(m\dot{z}) = 0$ and $\frac{d}{dt}(m\rho²\dot{\phi} + a\rho²) = 0$ and $\frac{dH}{dt} = 0$. Now I have to show that the solution for radial equation may be reduced to a quadrature $t = \int\frac{d\rho}{\sqrt{\alpha - (\beta - a\rho²)²/m²\rho²}}$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants. Can someone give me a suggestion to solve that?

Comment: You have three equations of the form $dX/dt = 0$. You can integrate something like that as $X = C$ for some constant $C$ - this is how the constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ will enter. Finally you can get the equation $t = \ldots$ starting from $d\rho/dt = \ldots$, so that's what you should aim for. (The trick is: $d\rho/dt = F \Rightarrow t = \int d\rho/F$.)

Comment: Starting from $\frac{d}{dt}(m\rho²\dot{\phi} + a\rho²) = 0$ we get $2m\rho\dot{\rho}\dot{\phi} + m\rho²\ddot{\phi} + 2a\rho\dot{\rho = 0}$ Now , can i affirm that $\ddot{\phi} = 0$ ?? Because $ \phi$ is a cyclical coordinate and solve $m\dot{\phi} + a =0$ for $\phi$

Comment: This question (v2) seems to confuse the Lagrangian and the Hamiltonian. There are no dotted variables in a Hamiltonian.

Comment: @PedroHenriqueGrosmanAlves No. You just have $m\rho^2\dot\Phi + a\rho^2 = \beta$, $\dot z = const$, $H = const.$ Use in expression for $H$,  and apply the trick suggested by Hans.

Comment: Dear Pedro, I fully agree with the advice by 'udrv'. You should not work out the time derivatives, instead use the fact that they are integrals of motion as I explained above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks guys, i followed your seggestion. Using $\dot{z} = const. =\alpha ' $ and $\dot{\phi}² = (\frac{\beta - a\rho²}{m\rho²})²$. Now applying on $H$ we have $\frac{d\rho}{dt} = \sqrt{\frac{H}{m} - \alpha'² - \rho²(\frac{\beta -a\rho²}{m\rho²})²}$ then $t = \int\frac{d\rho}{\sqrt{\alpha - \frac{(\beta - a\rho²)²}{m²\rho²}}}$  where $\alpha = \frac{H}{m} - \alpha'²$.